# Why the gstreamer pipeline won't play if I added a udpsink plugin to it

Tags: gstreamer, rtp

I tried to send an RTP stream with gstreamer, but I found that the pipeline won't play at all. When I simplified my code I found that if the udpsink plugin was added in the pipeline, the pipeline is blocked, and the status is always READY.

My code:

```cpp
#include <gst/gst.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  GstElement *pipeline, *source, *sink, *udp, *convert;
  GstBus *bus;
  GstMessage *msg;
  GstStateChangeReturn ret;
  gboolean terminate = FALSE;

  /* Initialize GStreamer */
  gst_init (&argc, &argv);

  /* Create the elements */
  source  = gst_element_factory_make ("videotestsrc", "source");
  convert = gst_element_factory_make ("videoconvert", "convert");
  sink    = gst_element_factory_make ("autovideosink", "sink");
  udp     = gst_element_factory_make ("udpsink", "udp");

  /* Create the empty pipeline */
  pipeline = gst_pipeline_new ("test-pipeline");

  /* Build the pipeline */
  gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN (pipeline), source, sink, convert, /*udp,*/ NULL);
  gst_element_link_many (source, convert, sink, NULL);

  /* Modify the source's properties */
  g_object_set (source, "pattern", 0, NULL);

  /* Start playing */
  ret = gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
  if (ret == GST_STATE_CHANGE_FAILURE) {
    g_printerr ("Unable to set the pipeline to the playing state.\n");
    gst_object_unref (pipeline);
    return -1;
  }

  bus = gst_element_get_bus (pipeline);
  do {
    msg = gst_bus_timed_pop_filtered (bus, GST_CLOCK_TIME_NONE, GST_MESSAGE_ERROR | GST_MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGED | GST_MESSAGE_EOS);

    /* Parse message */
    if (msg != NULL) {
      GError *err;
      gchar *debug_info;

      switch (GST_MESSAGE_TYPE (msg)) {
        case GST_MESSAGE_ERROR:
        case GST_MESSAGE_EOS:
          terminate = TRUE;
          break;
        case GST_MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGED:
          if (GST_MESSAGE_SRC (msg) == GST_OBJECT (pipeline)) {
            GstState old_state, new_state, pending_state;
            gst_message_parse_state_changed (msg, &old_state, &new_state, &pending_state);
            g_print ("Pipeline state changed from %s to %s\n", gst_element_state_get_name (old_state), gst_element_state_get_name (new_state));
          }
          break;
        default:
          /* We should not reach here because we only asked for ERRORs and EOS */
          g_printerr ("Unexpected message received.\n");
          break;
      }
      gst_message_unref (msg);
    }
  } while (!terminate);

  /* Free resources */
  // ...
}
```

As you can see, the pipeline works fine if the udpsink is not added. This also happens in command line:

```sh
gst-launch-1.0 -v udpsink videotestsrc ! videoconvert ! autovideosink
```

The command above will popup a window and the video stops at the first frame.

I don't know what's wrong with my code, can anyone give me help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A pipeline ends with a sink element, e.g. (`autovideosink`) you cannot add anything after that. That is why `autovideosink` does not have src pad and you can not link it to `udpsink`. You have to have a second thread linked to `udpsink`. To create threads you can use `queue` and `tee` elements.

You can find more [here (GStreamer Basic tutorial 7: Multithreading and Pad Availability)](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tutorials/basic/multithreading-and-pad-availability.html?gi-language=c)